# Pause HTML <video> tag on keypress when not typing into a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Currently, I have this, which is great but I have a text box under the video and when people try and type one of the letters or characters, it does something (like pausing or unpausing the videos), now I've tried to find a way to detect when the user is typing in the textbox but it doesn't ever seem to work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(window).keypress(function(e) {
  var video = document.getElementById('vid');
 var timeback = vid.currentTime - 5;
 var timeforward = vid.currentTime + 5;
 var volumeup = vid.volume + 0.5;
 var volumedown = vid.volume - 0.5;
  if (e.which == 107) {
    if (vid.paused == true)
      vid.play();
    else
      vid.pause();
  }
 if (e.which == 106) {
      vid.currentTime = timeback;
  }
 if (e.which == 108) {
      vid.currentTime = timeforward;
  }
 if (e.which == 109) {
 if(vid.muted == false){
  vid.muted = true; 
 }else{
  vid.muted = false;
 } 
  }
 if (e.which == 46) {
      vid.volume = volumeup;
  }
 if (e.which == 44) {
      vid.volume = volumedown;
  }
});

</script>
    <div align='center' class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
    <video id='vid' controls class='embed-responsive-item vid' onclick='this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();'>
         <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
 <form method='get' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <label for='comment'>Comment on this video:</label>
  <textarea name='comment' class='form-control textbox' rows='5' id='comment'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit'>
</form></div>
```

Comment: Does checking if the user has focus on the textbox solve the problem?

Comment: It might but I'd like for it to happen only when the user has clicked in the text box and is printing characters into the textbox.

Comment: Here's something to help: [`if ( document.activeElement === input ) { /* input focused */ } else { /* input not focused */ };`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) and to handle the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) and [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) events use [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) and [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur).

Comment: What text box? There isn't one in the HTML. Have you tried listening for key press events on the text box?

Comment: I forgot to add the textbox. But yes I have tried to add a listener for keypress events but whenever I add an else statement, it never works.

Comment: I can''t comment on why it didn't work because you haven't posted the code that was tried. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help improve question quality.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm quite new to StackOverflow and I removed the old listener since it would block out the keypresses completely whether I was on typing or not. Thanks for the answer though, really helped!

Comment: Calling `event.preventDefault` to see what it did  stopped key processing in the text area for me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1 - listen for textarea events

You can add a keypress event handler to the textarea and stop key press progation. That way, the event doesn't bubble up to the window listener and get processed by it.

This example just selects a `<textarea>` element and prevents anything except a TAB from going further (normally you can't type a TAB into an input). You could add an id attribute and use a different selector as required:

```
$("textarea").on( "keypress", function(e) {
    if(e.key !== "TAB") {
         e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Note the listener needs to be registered when the text area DOM element has been created and exists. Placing the HTML in the post before the script tags is one way of achieving this.

---

#### Method 2 - ignore textarea events

Alternatively you could allow events to bubble up the DOM as usual and add code to ignore them if they were originally fired on a textarea or input element:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {

    switch(e.target.tagName) {
        case "TEXTAREA":
        case "INPUT":
            return;  // do not process event at all
    }

        var video = document.getElementById('vid');
        // ... the video playback handler
});
```

This method has the advantage of being largely independent from page design. It doesn't require special event handlers to be added for standard elements that can be typed into (textarea and input), and returns immediately if the keypress was fired on such an element. Note tag names are in upper case in the DOM.